# Yahoo web hosting with cakephp

Tags: cakephp, web-hosting, yahoo

I have a problem with yahoo web hosting. I can't upload `.htaccess` files. So, my `cakephp` site is not working there.

how can correct this issue please help.

Comment: which type of server is this? its nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use cakephp without htaccess. See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#i-don-t-can-t-use-url-rewriting

Answer (score 2):

Can't upload `.htaccess` files?

Get a new hosting company.

Comment: Actually I am a developer and the client is not willing to change the hosting company.

Comment: Get a new client or do a better job explaining that their current hosting setup is terrible.

Comment: Not trying to be rude - just - pointing out that you're going to have trouble with them.  If not this, then the next time their site crashes they'll blame you.  Or if it runs slow, or if works intermittently...etc.  Not to mention, you'll likely have to develop it without using CakePHP, since you likely don't have access to what you need to do to get Cake to work without .htaccess files too...etc etc.  Just - seems like it's going to be an absolute pain if you can't convince them to move to a decent host.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your hosting provider to fix the issue Or else watch out for different web hosting provider who can provide best customer support for all technical issues.

Answer (score -1):

if you are not been able to upload .htaccess files through file sharing, try to upload with FTP. And still if not working, change web-host provider.
Or, else you can ask for same issue with your host provider.

Answer (score -1):

Just simply contact them, but I do agree that there are more advanced hostings that you can choose for the best price.  Whenever I face any problem with my hosting provider and they do not have answer for that this is a red flag.